# Back to top scroll var offset for different browser widths|heights

Tags: javascript, jquery

I implemented a "back to top" or "scroll to top" button in a WordPress site which works perfectly:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var offset = 500;
  var speed = 10;
  var duration = 250;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < offset) {
      $('.topbutton').fadeOut(duration);
    } else {
      $('.topbutton').fadeIn(duration);
    }
  });

  $('.topbutton').on('click', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, speed);
    return false;
  });
});
```

My dilemma is that I can't find a method to change the `var offset` to a flexible value according to browser width|height. Thus the narrower the browser/device screen, the further down the `500px` trigger point occurs, causing the "back to top" button to appear too late. Here is my CSS:

```css
.site-footer {
  background-color: #0a0a0a;
}

.topbutton {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url("https://sheknowsphotography.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Arrow-up-blue-ezgif.com-resize.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: none;
}
```

Here is the gif image inside the footer.php, just before the `</body>` tag:

```html
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<a href="#" class="topbutton"><img src="https://sheknowsphotography.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Arrow-up-blue-ezgif.com-resize.gif"></a>
```

Everything is done in child theme.

To whoever responds: thank you for your time!

Comment: You can solve this by retrieving the `height()` (or possibly the `offset.top + height`) of the element that you want to scroll to and setting that as the `offset` when the button is clicked

Comment: just use `$(window).height()` as offset and in/decrement until you like it

Comment: @John your solution works perfectly. I used `$(window).width()` instead, since all other media queries in WordPress are based on browser width, not height. This keeps things simpler for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 if ($(window).width() < 960) {
   var offset = 500;
 }
 else {
  var offset = 1000;
 }
    var speed = 10;
    var duration = 250;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() < offset) {
        $('.topbutton') .fadeOut(duration);
            } else {
        $('.topbutton') .fadeIn(duration);
            }
        });
 $('.topbutton').on('click', function(){
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, speed);
  return false;
  });
});
```